# QGIS plugin window qt creator formatting is ineffective

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt, pyqt

I am developing a QGIS plugin. I have assigned the QGIS main window as the parent window of custom plugin using:

```
QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, iface.mainWindow())
```

But after doing so the problem is that all the custom formatting in my plugin window which I did using qt creator is gone. I guess it is inheriting these properties from its parent window. Any ideas on how to restrain it from doing this?